# Possible to sort generic linked list in Java?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm trying to implement a k-means clustering algorithm (although that detail is not particularly important), and I wanted to make it work using generics in Java.

So in my main class I will call a cluster method. I was wondering if something like the following would be possible:

```
public static <T> void cluster(int k, LinkedList<T> list) {
  // Sort the list
  LinkedList<T> sortedList = Collections.sort(list);
  ...
}
```

Obviously the problem that I am running into is that T cannot be guaranteed to implement Comparable... But is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: I doubt that you will need this in k-means... **it never uses sorting** but apart from that, you need a `Comparator`, or a `Comparable` of course. Also, the runtime and efficiency of this code will be abyssal.

Comment: Apart from that, you *can* guarantee `<T>` to be `Comparable` by writing `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: According to my Algorithms Textbook (Kleinberg & Tardos), under Implementing Kruskal's Algorithm: "First we need to sort the edges by cost. This takes O(m log m). Since we have at most one edge between any pair of nodes, we have m <= n^2 and hence this running time is also O(m log n)."

But yes, extending Comparable seems to be the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Kruskal is not k-means.

Comment: True, but I was implementing k-means by using Kruskal and a Union-Find data structure.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, nor more efficient than regular k-means (which is O(n)). I can imagine Kruskal for hierarchical clustering but not k-means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void cluster(int k, List<T> list) {
    Collections.sort(list);
    ...
}
```

The `<T extends Comparable<T>>` makes sure that the `List<T>` holds `Comparable<T>` elements.

I used `List<T>` because the implementation (`LinkedList`, `ArrayList` etc.) doesn't matter - you access it via the `List` interface. But you can use `LinkedList<T>` instead if that's what you need.

And, `Collections.sort()` doesn't return anything, it sorts in-place.

Comment: Fantastic, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!